# Creating text buffer in legend QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, polygon, print-composer, qgis-2, legend

I work with this polygon layer and this is my map composer:

[image: example]

I used the labels with Text Buffer (yellow and red), and I try to find how I can make the same text buffer in the layer name in the legend.

I read [Text color in the legend of the print composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232622/text-color-in-the-legend-of-the-print-composer) and in it there a solution of creating a new text label. I don't want to do it in this way. I seeking a smart automatic way.

Comment: You can export map as SVG and add halo to legend text.